# Ruby - Relationship issues (has_one/has_many)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship

I'm trying to create a way to manage how many `Items` a `User` or `Event` has. I thought I could do this through another model, `ItemDatum`.

I was thinking that the `ItemDatum` would belong to either a `User`, or an `Event`, and `has_many` `Items`.

```
class ItemDatum < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :event

    belongs_to :user

    has_many :items
end
```

The `Event` would have one `ItemDatum` and have many `Items` through `ItemDatum`

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...

    has_one :item_datum, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :items, through: :item_datum
end
```

And `Items` would belong to many `ItemDatum`

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :item_datum

    ...
end
```

However this isn't quite working out and I don't have the knowledge to properly debug this.

Here are the migrations if that helps too:

```
class CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :events do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :text

      t.integer :location_id
      t.integer :item_datum_id

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end


class CreateItemData < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :item_data do |t|

      t.integer :item_id
      t.integer :event_id
      t.integer :user_id

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreateItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :items do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :description
      t.string :item_type
      t.integer :value
      t.integer :item_datum_id

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :items, :name, unique: true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>If you want an item to have many item datums, you're missing a table. I typically prefer to specify a model over using habtm.</s>

```
 rails g model ItemDataItem item_data_id:integer item_id:integer


 class ItemDataItem < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :item_data
   belongs_to :item
 end

 class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :item_data_items
   has_many :item_datum, through: :item_data_items
 end
```

Then on the ItemData class, add the same has_many and has_many through. I might have some of my names wrong with plurals, but it should do the trick.

**Edit**

For the item to belong to only one datum, simply update the item model:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item_datum

  ...
end
```

Comment: But the item should belong to the ItemDatum shouldn't it? Seems strange to me to have item data that has more item data

Comment: @EvanWard updated my answer. You have the item data id, all you really need a belongs_to. When the record holds the foreign key, it can only belong to one of those.

Comment: The problem is that I need items to be able to belong to any number of ItemData. So I want the Items table to only store unique items, but events and users can have many of those items.

Comment: Then my original answer was correct. You need a join table to connect a unique item to multiple data records.

Comment: Wouldn't `ItemDatum` also need to change to `has_many :itemDataItems` instead of `has_many :items` now?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I mentioned that at the bottom of my original answer, should have detailed it. You want `has_many :item_data_items`. `has_many :items, through: :item_data_items`

Comment: So i've taken this route, but adding items to events with `@event.items << @item` throws the error `Cannot modify association 'Event#items' because it goes through more than one other association.`

Comment: Yeah it's a bit of a complex setup to do that unfortunately. What you can do is: `@event.item_datum.items << item`